# How to assign an explicit value to a tag attribute in jQuery.

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I am creating dynamic drop-downs and assigning ajax data to one of the items attribute of c:forEach loop.I got data in alert, but I am missing something while assign it to "items" tag.Please tell me what is wrong.

HTML and jQuery code:

```
    <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
      <option value="">--Please select category--</option>
      <c:if test="${not empty productCategoryList}">
       <c:forEach items="${productCategoryList}" var="productCategory">
        <option id="catOptionId" value="${productCategory.pCatrgoryId}">${productCategory.pCategoryName}</option>
       </c:forEach>
      </c:if>
    </select>


    <select class="form-control" name="subCategory" id="subCategory">
      <c:if test="${not empty subCategoryList}">
       <c:forEach items="${subCategoryList}" var="subProductCategory">
        <option value="${subProductCategory.subCategoryId}">${subProductCategory.subCategoryName}</option>
       </c:forEach>
      </c:if>
    </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      //Dropdown select
      $("#subCategory").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#category").change(function() {
        var catId = $(this[this.selectedIndex]).val();
        alert(catId);
        if (catId != "" && catId != null) {
           $("#subCategory").attr("disabled", false);
           $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'getSubCatOnCat',
            data : {subCat : catId},
            success : function(data) {
               alert(data);
            // Problem is at this point.
               $("#subCategory c:forEach").attr("items",data);
            },
        error : function(xmlHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState = 0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0)
            return;
        },
        });
        }
       });
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: when you open inspect elements in your browser how your dropdown menu code looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of c:ForEach tag in jsp because jstl tags are handled at server side but option tags are handled at client side. So it's not possible to assign c:ForEach tag's variable value (always null) to option without submitting form.

**FIX :**

In jsp:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="subCategory" class="col-lg-1 control-label">SubCategory</label>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <select class="form-control" name="subCategory" id="subCategory">
        <option value="">--Please select sub-category--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In js:

```
var jsonSubCat = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
var $select = $('#subCategory');
$select.empty().prepend(
            "<option value='' selected='selected'>--Please select sub-category--</option>");
$(jsonSubCat).each(function(index,o) {
   var $option = $("   <option/>").attr("value",o.subCategoryId).text(o.subCategoryName);
            $select.append($option);
});
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. There is no need of c:ForEach tag in jsp because jstl tags are handled at server side but option tags are handled at client side. So its not possible to assign c:ForEach tag's variable value to option without submitting form.

**FIX :**

In jsp

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="subCategory" class="col-lg-1 control-label">SubCategory</label>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <select class="form-control" name="subCategory" id="subCategory">
        <option value="">--Please select sub-category--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In js

```
var jsonSubCat = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
var $select = $('#subCategory');
$select.empty().prepend(
            "<option value='' selected='selected'>--Please select sub-category--</option>");
$(jsonSubCat).each(function(index,o) {
   var $option = $("   <option/>").attr("value",o.subCategoryId).text(o.subCategoryName);
            $select.append($option);
});
```

I hope this will work for someone.